# What to write in Execute shell script in jenkins for executing automation scripts

Tags: macos, selenium, jenkins, webdriver

I am new to jenkins and I have no idea what to set in Build - Execute shell script. I want to execute my automation scripts through jenkins. I am using selenium webdriver for writing scripts and using mac osx. Can anyone help me step by step guide for executing it.

Comment: Did you use testng for your project?

Comment: yes i am using testng for project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Build Tab --> click on -> Add build step --> select Execute shell --> This will give you a command Box --> Just add the path of your script where you have saved it on your local 
example : sh /var/tmp/xyz.sh
Please note the script should be on the server where the Jenkins is hosted. 
FOr executing script on different host/system you need additional settings enabled.

Comment: Thank you .. but i want the format of how to write path of script in sh.

Comment: Format is simple . Like example : sh /var/tmp/xyz.sh